# Cant get my sql query with jpa and cruderepository to work, but works in a normal scheme

Tags: java, mysql, spring-data-jpa

I am new here, I been struggling with this query for a night now, would anyone help me?

here is the relevant code: https://hasteb.in/esuhiluf.java

When I made a pure SQL query in a scheme like this
https://hasteb.in/icopuxiq.sql
it worked, but when I add it to the interface and change the var names to the uppercases I can't get it to work, any help would be greatly appreciated :smile:
here is the error code:
Error creating bean with name 'productRepositories': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for the query for method public abstract java.util.List dev.rannem.storesql.repositories.ProductRepositories.getItemList(java.lang.Integer)!
```

Comment: Please post the code in the question, so it is there for posterity. Also because we are unlikely to follow links provided by unknown people to unknown sites.

Answer (score 0):

First: Check if CRUDRepository is the best for what you're trying to do. I started with CRUDRepository and switched to JPARepository, which extends CRUDRepository.

Second: Im assume your tableattributes are from the right tables - your SQL-Query does not match your @Query-String.

Last: Try to change your way of getting the id.

```
public interface ProductRepositories extends JPARepository<Product, Integer> {

@Query("select CartItem.product from Cart c join CartItem ci on ci.id = c.cartID join Cart.cartItems cci on c.cartID = cci.product.id where User.id = :id")
    List<Product> getItemList(Integer id);
}
```

Edit: Is your id really an Integer? Check your Product - it could be "long"

Comment: ProductId is a Integer, just doubled checked, tried your solution and sadly I still get the error.